# Alert blocking execution in Selenium for C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I ran into an issue while using Selenium that doesn't seem to make sense.

App being tested is an outdated aspx mishmash and the problematic execution does the following:

- Fill in a few fields within a `Form`
- Submit the form via button click
- Alert popup appears with confirmation ID

However, while being selenium tested, `Alert` seems to have a blocking effect on the whole process. After alert popup is displayed, every subsequent selenium line is being blocked including
`driver.SwitchTo().Alert()`, used to access and dismiss the popup.

If it makes a difference, submit button is inside an `iframe`.

Test eventually timeouts with generic `chrome not reachable` exception.

Using the latest versions of both ChromeDriver(2.45.0) and Selenium.WebDriver(3.141.0)

**Edit:**

After additional investigation looks like `iframe` is what's causing the issue. Calling `SwitchTo()` from `iframe` after alert is displayed, is blocking. So you can neither switch back to `DefaultContext`, nor switch to `Alert().Dismiss()`.

```
public void SubmitForm ()
{
    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("iframe1")));
    _driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton1")).Click();

    // Alert appears        

    // Just an extension method that tries `_driver.SwitchTo().Alert()`
    _driverWait.Until(c => c.AlertDisplayed()); // Blocked by alert

    _driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept(); // Not reached
}
```

**Edit 2:**

On Firefox driver, works without a hitch

Comment: I was troubleshooting https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9040, which looks like this issue (and while googling and ended up here). So this behaviour happens in Chrome but not in Safari or Firefox. Therefore it seems to be a Chrome/ChromeDriver issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to skip alert, you can disable the notifications with the code below;

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications"); // to disable notification
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

On the other hand, you might handle the alert by using code below;

```
options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Dismiss; //.accept, .dismiss, etc.
```

**Edit:**

Can you also try the following code?
ExpectedConditions is obselete. So you need to get `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` package from nuget and import that namespace into your class.

From:

```
_driverWait.Until(c => c.AlertDisplayed()); // Blocked by alert
```

To:

```
_driverWait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. In an ideal scenario, it would be great to be able to read the alert info and dismiss it. Automatically disabling it might be a bit restrictive.

Comment: @MilanVidakovic Could you please add code blocks that you are trying to run before alert and after alert?

Comment: SeleniumExtras.AlertIsPresent does the exact same thing as my extension, and it also gets blocked by the alert.